# TextFormField() issue while pasting from third party text editor

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

Hello guys There is a simple text in Notepad

[image]

when i copy this and paste it to my Text Form Field () widget flutter

i get this

[image]

i have to press space bar manually to get this

[image]

Comment: Can you include the copied Text from NotePad here

Comment: I've copied from noteBar and pasted on TextFormFiled, and it is working fine

Comment: yap I;ve tested on chrome, might be font issue you are using

Comment: Please copy any text having long space and try it  on TextFormField() and let me know.. thanks

Comment: oh.. thanks..i tried changing font. now it looks fine.

Comment: @Yeasin Sheikh..Please type 2 words in any text editor . and provide space with Keyboard's tab button and copy and paste it on TextFormField,   i tried with MS word and Notepad  when i copy and paste on TextFormField i get strange symbol for every Tab button i had pressed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue in Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77465) (at the time of this writing Flutter version 3.0.5). And it only happens on the `web` platform. The default font Flutter uses for `web` is missing a bunch of characters.

Comment: oh.. is it so ?

Comment: Unfortunately yes